# SQL - Update column value based on value from another table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 tables below and trying to update all values in tableA where applicable.

```sql
create table tableA(
key number(38,0),
tab1_uid varchar(500),
as_of_date date
)

create table TableB(
key number(38,0),
tab2_uid varchar(500),
as_of_date date
)

insert into tableA (key,tab1_uid,as_of_date) values (1,'123','2022-08-15'),(2,'345','2022-08-15'),(3,'256','2022-08-15');

insert into tableB (key,tab2_uid,as_of_date) values (0,'123','2022-08-18'),(0,'345','2022-08-18'),(1,'123','2022-08-17'),(2,'345','2022-08-17');
```

I want to update tableB key with tableA key values where tab1_uid = tab2_uid and tableB key = '0'

I tried doing below but getting Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated.

```sql
update tableB a 
set participant_key = (
  select b.key from tableA b 
  where a.tab2_uid = b.tab1_uid 
  and a.key = 0 and b.as_of_date = '2022-08-18'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the error.

I took the sample script, and changed `participant_key` to `key` (because the column `participant_key` doesn't exist anywhere), and the sample script run as expected:

```sql
create table tableA(
key number(38,0),
tab1_uid varchar(500),
as_of_date date
);

create table TableB(
key number(38,0),
tab2_uid varchar(500),
as_of_date date
);

insert into tableA (key,tab1_uid,as_of_date) values (1,'123','2022-08-15'),(2,'345','2022-08-15'),(3,'256','2022-08-15');

insert into tableB (key,tab2_uid,as_of_date) values (0,'123','2022-08-18'),(0,'345','2022-08-18'),(1,'123','2022-08-17'),(2,'345','2022-08-17');

update tableB a 
set key = (
  select b.key from tableA b 
  where a.tab2_uid = b.tab1_uid 
  and a.key = 0 and b.as_of_date = '2022-08-18'
);
```

[image]

Comment: update tableB a 
set key = (
  select b.key from tableA b 
  where a.tab2_uid = b.tab1_uid) 
  where a.key = 0;
  
Here is the error.  That query does not work as what I am trying to do. my mistake.